# Github permission denied (publickey) does not provide shell access

Tags: git, ssh

I was trying to run this command in a folder I cloned from git hub:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Then I got error messages saying that permission denied(publickey)
I tried to search this and ran this comment to create ssh key:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "xxx@xxx.com"
```

And added ssh key via website,and ran command below to check if it was fixed:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

But it told me that I've successfully authenticated but GitHub dose not provide shell access.Then I ran this command to debug:

```
ssh -vT git@github.com
```

And here is the output:

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1 Ubuntu-10, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.255.112] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/edison/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/edison/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/edison/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/edison/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/edison/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/edison/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/edison/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/edison/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Ubuntu-10
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh-0.7.0
debug1: no match: libssh-0.7.0
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/edison/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/edison/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.com ([192.30.255.112]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_MEASUREMENT = zh_CN.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_PAPER = zh_CN.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_MONETARY = zh_CN.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_NAME = zh_CN.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_ADDRESS = zh_CN.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_NUMERIC = zh_CN.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TELEPHONE = zh_CN.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_IDENTIFICATION = zh_CN.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TIME = zh_CN.UTF-8
Hi edisonguocat! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 3208, received 1776 bytes, in 3.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 1062.4, received 588.1
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

> I ran the first command in my post:`git submodule update --init --recursive` and it still told me `Permission denied (publickey)`

That depends on the URL of the submodule, that you can read in your `.gitmodules` file of your repo.
Or it could depend on the URL of th submodule of one submodule, but if no submodule is cloned, if the error is displayed immediately, the issue should be limited to your immediate first-level submodules.

So double-check the url(s) present in the `.gitmodules` files: one of them might reference a private repo, that your authentication does not give you access to.

Answer (score 0):

This is good, not an error.

It means your keys work, and you should be able to use the `git` command to access your repository.

Even though git uses the ssh protocol and login mechanism, you are not allowed to ssh into a full shell session on Github's server. But you don't need that anyway.

Comment: Again I ran the first command in my post:git submodule... and it still told me Permission denied (publickey) Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Can you manually `git clone` the submodules? Is there more than one (I noticed the --recursive)? Did you add the key to all these repositories?

Comment: Also not close to a complete answer. There are clearly more steps to be taken and a big picture overview of what is going on is not even attempted to be provided.